# Describing REST services using WSDL

Tags: web-services, rest, wsdl

I understand that you can describe your REST webservice while using WSDL.
Is this a good idea if you don't use WCF? Is there a better way to allow service discovery and bind your request/response to certain types?
If you use json you can use SMD and JSON-Schema but what if you use XML or YAML?

EDIT:
I have found this specification for WADL.
How widely used is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Http Accept header and Content Type headers are there to allow a client to dynamically request and respond to different types.  Statically describing what those types are in some kind of description file like WSDL would be unnecessarily limiting.

The use of hyperlinks within the returned representations allows for incremental service discovery.  This allows the service discovery to be dynamic based on a whole range of factors.

The use of a global static service discovery document like WSDL or WADL is really not the optimum solution with a REST service.

Comment: @the_drow  For the same reasons WSDL in not needed.  Search of other WADL related questions, there are plenty here.